# Based on large text layout changes in android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Hi In My application I am designing one application with 8 icons if i give the name for each textview's my layout got changes I want all the vertical and horizontal layout must be same with good looking mode.left side imagebutton's and textview's i want to give space like right side view.

Can any one please help me

**xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:weightSum="2.0">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/student" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="AboutUs" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
         android:layout_weight="1.0">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/student" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Play Group" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
     android:weightSum="2.0"
     >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_weight="1.0">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/student" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Facilites" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/student" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tour Our School" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
     android:weightSum="2.0"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_weight="1.0">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/student" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Carrers" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_weight="1.0">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/student" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Admission Enquiry" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
     android:weightSum="2.0"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_weight="1.0">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/student" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Parents Resoures" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_weight="1.0">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/student" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ContactUs" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

PREVIEW:

[image]

Comment: Can you add screenshots of what you want and what you get?

Comment: u got the screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:gravity="center"` in all Sub `LinearLayout` like:

I have edited whole layout...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2.0" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/student" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="AboutUs" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/student" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Play Group" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2.0" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/student" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Facilites" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/student" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tour Our School" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2.0" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/student" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Carrers" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/student" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Admission Enquiry" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2.0" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/student" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Parents Resoures" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/student" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ContactUs" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

> Note: You have to do that if you have to give `layout_weight`
>   parameter in `LinearLayout` then give also `layout_width="0dp"`

Thanks

Comment: how to give space between first linearlayout to linearlayout horizontal

Comment: add `layout_margin="10dp"`and please Learn Basics of Android Layout Properties.